# Magento Price Change Module

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have created a module to change the prices of a product when added to cart, but the module doesn't get to the method.

The observer.php file and the class `Zain_ProductLabelPricing_Model` is running but the method 'modifyPrice' is not. Can someone guide me how to fix this?

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <models>
            <chdispatcher>
                <class>Zain_ProductLabelPricing_Model</class>
            </chdispatcher>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <modify_to_custom_price>
                        <class>chdispatcher/observer</class>
                        <method>modifyPrice</method>
                    </modify_to_custom_price>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php
// die(); this is working
class Zain_ProductLabelPricing_Model {
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs) {
        //die(); this is not working
        Mage::log('This worked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event configuration is looking for the model `Zain_ProductLabelPricing_Model_Observer`.  This is derived from `chdispatcher/observer` which is translated to: *module*/**model**.

Just add `_Observer` to your class name and place the file in the folder `Zain/ProductLabelPricing/Model` with the filename `Observer.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The class must be named `Zain_ProductLabelPricing_Model_Observer`

The only reason, why your `die()` is executed, is that Magento loads `Observer.php` to look for this observer class. It does not find it, so the next thing that happens is a "class not found" error.